# Как сделать таймер в Inno setup?

Tags: inno-setup

У меня есть код, который проигрывает звук при открытии страницы выбора папки установки. Этот звук звучит бесконечно. Как сделать так, что-бы он звучал один раз.

```
var
 UTimer: TTimer;  //Таймер для обновления событий

procedure UpdateTimer(Sender: TObject);
begin
sndPlaySound(pSoundMemory_C, SND_MEMORY or SND_NODEFAULT or SND_ASYNC);
end;


procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
 UTimer:= TTimer.Create(WizardForm);
 UTimer.Interval:= 1000;
 UTimer.OnTimer
 UTimer.OnTimer:= @UpdateTimer;
end;

procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
 UTimer.Enabled:= False;
if CurPageID=wpSelectDir then begin
 UTimer.Enabled:= True;
end;
end;
```